# How to lower the cost of realtime lights?

Tags: rendering, performance, lighting

Besides Deferred rendering, what can I do to make realtime lights cheaper to render? I don't really need them but I could make good use of them in my game.
BTW I thought Deferred render would give me a bigger boost on scenes with many lights but I got kinda let down. Maybe my expectations were too high.

Comment: It might help to post some code so people can see how you're currently handling them.